# edit text on text changed to avoid duplicates

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, android-cursoradapter, textwatcher

When creating list view using cursor adapter , edit text in the list view gets duplicate values.I have no idea about what to write in my edit text's on text changed method. please help..
below shown is my class to view data on list, which is called from my on create methode

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.orders);
    list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
     this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
     databas.clear();



    curserdata();
}
private void curserdata() {
    DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this.getApplicationContext());
    newDB = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c = dbHelper.DataP();

      // The desired columns to be bound
      String[] columns = new String[] {
              dbHelper.name,
              dbHelper.mail,
              dbHelper.num,

      };

      // the XML defined views which the data will be bound to
      int[] to = new int[] { 
        R.id.name,
        R.id.mail,
        R.id.num,

      };

      // create the adapter using the cursor pointing to the desired data 
      //as well as the layout information
      dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
        this, R.layout.list_simple_row, c, columns, to,0);

      // Assign adapter to ListView
      list.setAdapter(dataAdapter);


       EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addrs);
      text.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

       public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
       }

       public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, 
         int count, int after) {
       }

       public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, 
         int before, int count) {
        //dataAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
       }
      });



     }
```

here is my list_simple_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:shrinkColumns="*"
android:stretchColumns="*" 
android:layout_margin="4dp"
 >



<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:text=""
          android:gravity="center"
         android:layout_span="4"

        >
    </TextView>
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mail"
        android:text=""
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
         android:layout_span="4"
        >
    </TextView>
  <EditText
        android:id="@+id/num"
       android:inputType="number"
         android:text=""
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
         android:layout_span="4"
         >
    </EditText>
  <EditText
        android:id="@+id/addrs"
         android:gravity="center_horizontal"
         android:inputType="number"
         android:text=""
         android:layout_span="4">
        </EditText>
             </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: What do you want to accomplish  with TextChangedListener actually?

Comment: actually when i enter anything to the edit text , its getting duplicated when i am scrolling.I even tried custom adapter, but through dat i cant set my text view values properly.all i want is not to duplicate value in edittext while scrolling

Comment: getting duplicated means? where the duplicate text is being shown ? Where is your EditText in the list ? Simply this much of code doesn't describe the problem...